# Jquery is not defined when remove "text/javascript" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, web

**Scenario that works:**

- I have an `APP_FRAMEWORK.JS` file that was generated through a `WEBPACK`, including `BOOTSTRAP AND JQUERY` inside it.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app_framework.js') }}" defer></script>

  @if(!empty($assets['js']))
      @foreach ($assets['js'] as $js)
          <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset($js) }}"></script>
      @endforeach
  @endif
  ```

If I load the page as in the example, it works perfectly, without any errors in the scripts that are loaded inside that loop below.

**My question:**

- Why, if I remove the "text/javascript" when loading the `MAIN SCRIPT (APP_FRAMEWORK.JS)` the `$ is not defined` error starts to appear?
- Remembering that this `TYPE` is no longer mandatory, scripts are loaded in the correct order and there is a `DEFER`!!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: "_if I remove the "text/javascript"_" You remove `"text/javascript"` or `type="text/javascript"`?

Comment: type="text/javascript"

Comment: Version : `"version": "3.6.0"`

Comment: it's not problem with `type="text/javascript"`, just don't `defer` the jquery

Comment: @VitaliyRayets, thanks for the suggestion. I researched a little more about `defer` and understood that actually, `defer` doesn't guarantee me asynchronicity if the other elements don't have this attribute either. take a look below at the answer and surveys I posted, hugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Forcing the browser not to load scripts from cache (**SHIFT + RELOAD** on Mac)
   [image]
   Just by doing that, we already see that the `APP_FRAMEWORK.JS` is being loaded after the others.
2. Another point, `defer` does not prevent other scripts from being loaded until those that have it defined carry out their process. The definition of the `defer` attribute goes further, being:

   ***The `defer` attribute tells the browser to run the script only when the HTML parsing is finished.
   The script will be requested asynchronously, its download will be completed and, only when the analysis of the HTML document is finished, will it be executed. Even if the full script download happens before the full HTML parsing, it won't run until later.
   If you have multiple script elements with the `defer` attribute,
   they will be requested in parallel and executed in the stated sequence.***
3. As the scripts are at the bottom of the page, there is no need to use `defer`, as it will never stop interpreting the HTML to download any JS.
4. The problem itself has nothing to do with `type="text/javascript"`, everything is related to the size of the loaded scripts, download time, in view of the order of dependency and execution.
5. If you really need to follow a JS loading order, `defer` must be used in all `<script defer>`, so that it follows the declared sequence, thus:

```
<script defer src="{{ asset('js/app_framework.js') }}" defer></script>
<script defer src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"> others ...</script>

@if(!empty($assets['js']))
    @foreach ($assets['js'] as $js)
        <script defer src="{{ asset($js) }}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

[image]

Refer link: https://www.braziljs.org/p/diferencas-entre-async-e-defer

And now comes the question that doesn't want to shut up...
Why, even loading the files from the cache in the correct order, the browser displayed the message?

Has anyone heard of `error cache` from the browser based on those files? Like, see that the scripts are the same, that the last execution of those scripts gave an error and already display the error automatically?